# Hidden Navigation Bar Revealed on Hover But Not Full Width

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a script I found that allows me to hide a div within an outer div. When the outer div is hovered over the inner div appears. However both the outer and inner div are set to 100% width in CSS and without the script they work properly, spannning the entire width of the screen. With the script they span to only the min-width I set.

This is meant to be a menu bar that spans the entire width of the site at the very top.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a solution to get the `div` back to the full width of the screen? Hoping it's something simple I missed.

```
<div id="menu_outer_wrapper" 
         onmouseover="document.getElementById('menu_strip_wrapper')
         .style.visibility = 'visible';" 
         onmouseout="document.getElementById('menu_strip_wrapper')
         .style.visibility = 'hidden';">
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
#menu_outer_wrapper {
 height: 40px:
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 min-width: 800px;
} 

#menu_strip_wrapper {
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 800px; 
 background: #f1f1f2;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Comment: Since this was solved with a pretty simple fix. Small oversight on my part. Maybe I can add to it another problem I'm having with the javascript itself.

It works, it hides the div, but only after you've mouse over the div and then mouse out. When you first load the page, the div is visible and will remain visible unless you mouse over it and then mouse out. Is there a way to get it to hide the div by default?

Answer (score 0):

Change `:` to `;` and see if it will work.

```css
#menu_outer_wrapper { height: 40px: }
```

[jsfiddle.net/7maCW/](http://jsfiddle.net/7maCW/)

Comment: Thank you. I just realized this myself and came back to delete this post. Can't believe I missed that little colon.